# Unable to locate package in katoolin

Tags: 14.04, katoolin

I'm having problems with `katoolin`.

After using "view  categories" to download all
tools available there,

I get this error: `E: Unable to locate package webshag`

I'm running 14.04

Comment: I have experienced this exact issue also, in ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04. I believe that there is an issue with the repository that katoolin installs and how the program interacts with the errors being produced. I have successfully gone through almost every package and installed it manually using the categories inside of the program. Unfortunatly I have not been able to find a fix for the issue so it will be interesting to see what others can come up with :)

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` after adding the new package repositories?

Comment: Yes. and still same error

Answer (score 0):

I tried opening the application through Python (sudo python katoolin.py). I used option 1 to install and update the repositories and after that I tried to install the kali linux tools and all of them could get installed. This workaround can help you maybe (I am using Ubuntu 16.04). Hope this helps.